# What is the closest gas to ideal at STP?

Tags: ideal-gas

I assume it is probably one of the noble gases eg Helium or Argon, but is this true?

Comment: In what regard do you mean "closest"?

Comment: How about  https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111108161615AAu4wRg

Comment: I presume a criterion such as smallest values of the $a$ and $b$ corrections in the [van der Waals law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) would define your notion of "closest"?

Comment: Briefly, the gas whose speed of sound at a given temperature (and atmospheric) pressure is closest to theoretical values

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a single answer to this, but I would approach it by using the [Van der Waals equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) to describe the gas. Then the gas with the lowest values for the Van der Waals coefficients $a$ and $b$ would be the closest to ideal. Judging by the [table of values that Wikipedia supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_(data_page)) helium seems to be the most ideal with $a = 0.0346$ L$^2$bar/mol$^2$ and $b = 0.0238$ L/mol.